# facebook oauth manage pages php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that posts to people's Facebook pages and profiles.  The below code has been in place for about 2 years.  Now, for new users, when my app logs into Facebook and asks for permissions, it does not ask for manage_pages, even though its explicitly listed below.

Did something on the Facebook side change which requires me to change my code?

Thanks,
Brian

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["code"]))
    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
      $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); // CSRF protection
      $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
   . $FBAPPID . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
   . $_SESSION['state'] .     "&scope=publish_actions,manage_pages,publish_pages";

 header("Location: " . $dialog_url);
 exit;
   }

   if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] === $_REQUEST['state'])) {
     // state variable matches
       $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $FBAPPID . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $FBSECRET . "&code=" . $code;

       $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
```

... (more stuff)

Comment: You need to get `manage_pages` approved by Facebook now, before you can ask common users for it (and most other permissions as well). Go read their documentation about login, the review process is explained in there in great detail.

Comment: Please check Facebook docs and remember to be updated with all changes. This change was announced 1 year ago: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review